# Call Java lib (class function) from python

Tags: java, python, c++, jar

Recently I wrote C++ extention for python I used http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_further_extensions.htm to use c++ class, library as python module.

Now I have to do the same with java instead of c++. I have big libraries written in java. I want to make a bridge for python programmers to use that libraries.

which is the best way to make python access to java libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You have basically two option.
Wrap java library into c++ library using JNI or wrap it into server and access to it using tcp (HTTP REST for example) or some kind of named pipes available on your OS.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think you understand me wrong, I want to write extensin for python or somehow to access java libs from python.

Comment: There is no direct way to call Java from python. You will need intermediate layer in C/C++